# Why converting from string to int results in weird value

Tags: string, f#, int

I'm new to F# and I was having trouble finding the last element of an number-string and converting that element to an int. So if the string was "123", then I would want to get back 3. However, this code:

```
  let s (a : string) =
      let x = a.[0]
      int x
```

This gives me back 49 when I do `s "123"`. I can't figure out why this is happening. Also, when I input the string "124" it still gives me 49. Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: `a.[0]` is `'1'`, for which the value 49 is the [ASCII code](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg/2000px-ASCII-Table-wide.svg.png). If you want the integer representation of the entire string, just do `int a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a.[0]` returns the first *character* of `a`: `'1'`. Casting a character to `int` returns its [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/). You need to call `int` on a *string* instead:

```
let x = a.Substring(a.Length - 1)
int x
```

(I've used standard .Net methods on the first line; the F# standard library also has functions to do the same.)

Comment: @user123082 : "*Is there like a builtin way to do this?*" Is that not exactly what the `int` operator is?

Comment: you could rename `int` to `s` : `let s x = int (x:string)`

Comment: @user123082 A built-in way to do what specifically?

Comment: @user123082 `Int32.TryParse` is the best way to do what you want. It returns a tuple of a boolean (indicates if the parsing succeeded) and an integer (holds the parsed value, if the parsing succeeded, otherwise 0). Use it like `let (ok, x) = Int32.TryParse "123"`.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed by indexing into a string, F# treats it as a character array.
Take a look at: [ASCII Table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

int '1' is basically the integer value for the character '1'

You probably want `int "1"` or `Int32.Parse("1")` or `Int32.TryParse`

[Parsing Numeric Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbtzcc4w(v=vs.110).aspx)